# C#: How do I compare two input int values

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am wondering how do I compare two input int values.
I understand that I need to have an if/else condition.
But I am confused as to where do I store these values for comparison.

So if currentNum > previousNum, it'll print out the currentNum.
if previousNum is higher than the current num, nothing happens.

Then it goes on and on whenever I click the 'Click Event'

Sorry, I am unable to provide the codes as I do not know where to start.

Here's how the the form looks like:

[image: here's how the the form looks like]

Comment: How about posting the code related to the click event?

Comment: you'd want to parse the textbox's text into an int.  Something along the lines of `int num = int.Parse(numberTextBox.Text)`

Comment: You need to look in the designer and see what the names of the textboxes are. Once you know that, you can convert the values to ints by doing `int val = int.Parse(txtWhatever.Text);`

Comment: yup, I do get that I need to convert the values in the textBox to int inorder to compare. But how would I do that? If my previous value was stored into num and my current value would be stored into num since theyre both the input from the textBox.

Comment: the textbox that you can edit value should be a local variable in the method (probably on click event) and your highest number should be a global variable in the class. And ofcourse the names should be different. After you compare the values, assign a new value to highest number variable when you need.

Comment: It looks to me like the previous num is stored in a different textbox. What am I missing?

Comment: probably a class-scoped variable to hold the `previousNum`

Comment: int num;
            num = int.Parse(textBoxNo.Text);
            prevNum = int.Parse(textBoxNo.Text);

            if (num > prevNum)
            {
                textBoxHighestNo.Text = num.ToString();
            }
            else
                textBoxHighestNo.Text = prevNum.ToString();
        } how do i use the code markdown? :<
I've tried this in the Click event but it did not work..

Answer (score 0):

Try this for example:

```
 int var1, var2 = 0;
  var1 = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBox1.Text);
  var2 = Convert.ToInt32(this.textBox2.Text);

     if (var1 < var2)
            code here
        else
           code here
```

Comment: i would consider TryParse instead of Convert, as you never know what type of junk a person will type into a box.

Comment: Sorry, Convert.ToInt32 actually throws FormatException and OverflowException, so there is actually ways to check this.

Comment: I would be inputting the numbers onto the same textBox. So the comparison is actually between the previous number and the current one

Comment: Maybe you should try with a button to save the first value and then clear the textbox and write second value, that is the only way I can think right now.

Comment: @Droa you should avoid exceptions if you can as they add a lot of overhead. The `TryParse` approach you suggested is the right one to use.